# Username and Email validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Entity Framework and trying to do a validation on my `Email` and `Username` fields on the edit user View. I know how to do the validation but I could not find where to do that.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Company, Model.Companies.Select(company => new SelectListItem()
       {

           Text = company,
           Value = company,
           Selected = company == Model.Company
       }), new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10 pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ManageUsers")'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> @FMS.Resources.Global.back</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> @FMS.Resources.Global.save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the `Name` and `Company` fields I easily did the validation because they both are on the `ApplicationUser` model (check below). The problem is that `Email` and `Username` are not there because they are inherited.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_cannot_be_empty", 
              ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FMS.Resources.Global))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Companies { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_cannot_be_empty", 
              ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FMS.Resources.Global))]
    public string Company{ get; set; }
```

If I try to define `Email` and `username` on the above model it says that it is already defined ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEauB.jpg)). The problem is that I cannot find where so I can put the validation there.

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggests? Add `override` to the properties?

Comment: You should add override to your properties
   `public override string Email { get; set; }`

Comment: @bnu Thank you very much. I solved it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined in the base class as `virtual`:

```
public virtual string Email { get; set; }
public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
```

So you need to [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) this properties and add your annotation. Like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_cannot_be_empty", 
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FMS.Resources.Global))]
public override string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it with your suggestion. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As @S.Akbari says you can override base properties and solve the problem. But there are other approaches to do this. So everything that is achieved with **DataAnnotations** should be achieved with EF **Fluent API**.

So here is the example:

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IdentityUser> IdentityUser{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Property(p => p.Email).HasMaxLength(25);
    }
}
```

You should check this article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193959(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I solved the problem with the @S.Akbari solution but thank you very much for pointed an alternative approach. Always good to learn different point of view. Thanks!

Comment: I personally think that validations are better done in the model using Data Annotations, because by the time you reach EF, you've already passed any business logic, which should have been aborted if the data is invalid.

Comment: @Tsahi Asher I completely agree with you, but still there are cases which need validation just before entering the data into Data Base, simply because the logic is in it. For example you can insert data directly into DB with WCF data service and URL $filter option.